# Hypercontractive inequality for random walks on sets

Tags: reference-request, random-walks, spectral-graph-theory, association-schemes

Let $k<N$ be natural numbers. In this question we consider graphs whose vertices are size-$k$ subsets of a size-$N$ universe. Consider the following random walk in the graph:

Starting from a set $R$ pick $t$ elements in $R$ uniformly at random and pick a uniformly random set $S$ that contains those $t$ elements ($t$ is a parameter; note that the size of the intersection of $S$ and $R$ may be larger than $t$).

This model is studied in the association schemes literature and has an elegant spectral analysis (see, e.g., https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~cgodsil/pdfs/assoc2.pdf).

My question is whether one can prove a hypercontractive inequality in this model (equivalently, a Log Sobolev constant), similarly to what's proven for closely related models in
https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aop/1022855885.

Comment: Quite likely. However, could you, please, state the inequality you want explicitly and in as low tech language as you can? You definitely have $\pi$ uniform, etc., Also  you know what bounds and in what form are interesting to you and what bounds are too weak for your purposes and we do not. :-)